# 文字列で返されたhash内でkeyが決まった数値以上のvalueを出力したい

Tags: ruby

```
hash = {"1.3"=>"53.0", "3.4"=>"50.30", "2.5"=>"1.600", "7.4"=>"63.0", "4.9"=>"103.400", "3.2"=>"13.400"}
```

a = 3.0
上記のような場合にkeyがa（3.0）以上のvalue値を返したいのですがなかなか上手くいきません。

上の場合だと

```
{"3.4"=>"50.30","7.4"=>"63.0","4.9"=>"103.400", "3.2"=>"13.400"}
```

もしくはvalue値のみで

```
{50.30, 63.0, 103.400, 13.400}
```

と返したいです。
何かいい方法をご存知の方は教えていただけるとありがたいです。

また、hashでkeyもvalue文字列の場合にhashの形は保ったまま文字列 → 数値に変更する方法はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 聞きたいことが複数ある場合は「また」で繋げず質問をわけてもいいかもしれません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash#select` でどうでしょう
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Hash/i/filter.html

```
hash = {"1.3"=>"53.0", "3.4"=>"50.30", "2.5"=>"1.600", "7.4"=>"63.0", "4.9"=>"103.400", "3.2"=>"13.400"}
a = 3.0
hash.select {|k| k.to_f >= a }
# => {"3.4"=>"50.30", "7.4"=>"63.0", "4.9"=>"103.400", "3.2"=>"13.400"}
```